# Exclude present term from loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have foreach loop that prints all the categories from a certain post type.
In my taxonomy page, I would like to print all the terms that belong to that taxonomy but not the present term. How can I do it using a for loop?

```
$presentTerm = get_queried_object();

$terms = get_terms('success-storiescat');
foreach ($terms as $key => $term && $term != $presentTerm) {
  $link = get_term_link($term);
  echo '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just add the condition to the `foreach()` you could do it inside the loop...

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
    if ($term != $presentTerm) {
        $link = get_term_link($term);
        echo '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put into an array $presentTerm and use array_diff for filter like

```
$terms= array_diff($value, $exclude);
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
$link = get_term_link($term);
echo '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
}
```